# What exactly carries energy in a transformer from primary to secondary?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetic-flux, power-transfer

Suppose we have applied a voltage to a transformer with an open secondary, we will get a certain flux in the core and a certain voltage at the secondary depending upon the turns ratio.

Now, suppose we connect resistance to the secondary and therefore current will start to flow through it and a reflected current will flow in the transformer's primary winding. But the magnitude of flux remains the same with or without the load.

So my question is: What exactly changes when we connect a load to the transformer, which results in power transfer from primary to secondary? In short, which magnetic parameter is responsible for power transfer between primary and secondary?

As far I understand, change in flux induces a voltage but does not carry any power, and change in flux remains the same with or without the load.

Comment: It's magnetism, so it's carried by photons. but this is probably not a useful answer.

Comment: @Jasen, this seems interesting. Can you please explain a little bit more or provide some source for me to read?

Comment: Unified field theory has photons responsible for electromagnetism. I don't understand the details.  It's a physics thing not an engineering thing.  I can't understand how a photon with a 600km wavelength can stay inside a transformer smaller than my fist.  maybe ask in the physics stack exchange,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changing flux in the core creates a 'volts per turn' around the core. This is the voltage that perfectly opposes the input voltage on the primary, and generates the secondary output voltage.

When a secondary current flows in phase with this voltage, power is abstracted. The same power is delivered by the primary current flowing in phase (or to keep sign convention with the secondary current flow, anti-phase) with this voltage.

> So my question is: What exactly changes when we connect a load to the transformer, which results in power transfer from primary to secondary?

The primary and secondary currents change. We know that a current flow through a voltage difference moves energy.

> In short, which magnetic parameter is responsible for power transfer between primary and secondary?

The only thing connecting the primary and the secondary is the magnetic, or electromagnetic, field coupling both windings. It is therefore the field.

At this point, you need to examine what you are actually looking for. Do you want an equation which predicts the magnitude of the various effects, or do you want to know **why** they are happening.

Most engineers would be happy with equations to predict how ideal, and non-ideal, transformers behave. In that sense, your question might be better asked on the physics stack, where they are interested in more fundamental things.

But wait, physicists only produce equations to predict what's going to happen, an  elaborate method of book-keeping. For instance power flow in electromagnetism is described in  terms of the Poynting Vector, the cross product of voltage and current, which actually identifies that power flow occurs not inside copper wire, but in the fields in space surrounding them. So if you dip into physics, you find that power flow in a wire is already non-intuitive, and you haven't got to anything as complicated as a transformer yet.

Maxwell's equations will tell you what changes in current and field will produce other changes in field and current, but not why. Quantum mechanics will tell you what's likely to happen when you set up an experiment involving charged particles but not why, absolutely certainly not why. And then those particles are best thought of as excitations in fields anyway.

At the bottom, there's 'If it Happens, it Must be True'. Ideal transformer equations, Maxwell's equations, the Poynting Vector, all described what we see, experimentally. Live with the transformer equations long enough so that your intuition aligns with what happens, and then you'll intuitively get them.

Consider a mechanical analogy. Take two magnets and align them same poles facing, so they repel. Push the first magnet, and let the second magnet move. When you push the first magnet, you do work on it, it does work on the field, the field does work on the second magnet, which moves away and does work on something else. You haven't stored any energy in the field, and the energy has somehow been transferred from the first to the second magnet, through the field. The field could easily be constant in strength and the magnet spacing stay the same during this operation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Neil_UK. "The only thing connecting the primary and the secondary is the magnetic, or electromagnetic, field coupling both windings. It is therefore the field." - That was my first guess too but the only thing bugging me is since flux is the same, which is just B/A, therefore B didn't change, so if amplitude of field didn't change, how did the energy carried by the field changed, but you're right it's kind of a non-sense question, and I, myself am not sure what exactly I am hoping for as the answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AnujMaheshwari I've added a last paragraph.

Comment: @AnujMaheshwari Really your question should have been closed as a duplicate. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164819/how-does-a-transformer-transmit-power-from-the-primary-to-the-secondary?rq=1) is an answer by someone who's taken a lot more trouble to spell out some equations. I'm not sure it explains, as in explains, anything though, though the concept of a positive flux from the primary and a negative flux from the secondary is tantalising.

Comment: I asked this question to someone I know before posting it here and he gave the same answer, but the problem as I see with this explanation is if positive flux is taking power from primary to secondary, the equal and opposite flux created by secondary should dump the same power back to primary, anyways I don't think this question is well formed and have a close formed answer. But the insights given by your answer and in the one given in the second answer is really good.

Answer (score 7):

The *net* (total) flux remains constant.

When you allow a current to flow in the secondary, it creates its own flux in the core that partially cancels the flux originally produced by the primary. More current flows in the primary to create flux that "makes up" the difference.

Comment: Exactly, so as far as magnetics is considered, nothing changed (what I mean is the value of flux didn't change) after adding load, but now power is being transferred from primary to secondary, what physical parameter is carrying that power. In short, without any change in flux, how did the power carried by flux increased or am I completely off and power is carried from primary to secondary by something else entirely.

Comment: @AnujMaheshwari, consider if you have an AWG 28 wire carrying 1 A @ 110 V, and you replace it with an AWG 8 wire, the current will remain 1 A, and the delivered power will remain 110 W, despite there being 100 times as many electrons "carrying" the power.

Comment: @ThePhoton Number of electrons doesn't change by changing the thickness of wire, if I am correct, thickness only changes the relative ease with which the electrons can move, that is it changes resistance of the wire, current literally is dq/dt, so for 1A of current ,1C of charge needs to flow which fixes the number of electrons by definition, doesn't it?

Comment: @AnujMaheshwari, it certainly does change. Each copper atom provides one free electron. An AWG 8 wire has more copper atoms per mm of length than an AWG 28 wire.

Comment: All atoms may provide a free electron , but not all off them "flow", which actually carries the power.

Comment: @AnujMaheshwari, all of them are influenced by the same electric field, although their motion is randomized by scattering off the lattice atoms (or the phonons in the lattice, depending how you want to look at it). All the free electrons in the wire contribute equally to the current, if you average over a long enough time (maybe microseconds).

Answer (score -1):

Ferromagnetic materials have an extra layer of electrons which hold the momentum induced by the fluctuating flux and is transferred by induction itself again through electromagnetism